# Is $y^2$ an even function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, even-and-odd-functions

### yesterday I asked this question

the solution of this problem says that since $y^2$ is an even function and so is $cosx-1$ therefore $y'$ is an even function which implies $y$ is odd function and from there on the solution builds up

I can not understand how is $y(x)^2$ even??

here is the full solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI3UBYJ21iw&t=98s

[image]

**and people here on stackexchange told he that the solution is wrong, which is what I was thinking too but today I encounter the same approach again and both the times the answer though this approach is correct which made me confused, how is $y^2$ even?**

I am getting more confused now here is one more example where $y^2$ is taken to be even

this is the solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnqOCpqUebQ
[image]

what's going on???

I am also looking for the correct solution of the second problem, the first problem I was able to solve myself

Comment: to be able to say that $y^2$ is a functions.
you must be able to say that $\forall x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R} $ that $x_{1}= x_{2}$ so $y(x_1)= y(x_2) = g(x)$. the problem for $y^2%$ is that $y(x)=g(x)=-g(x)$ so its not a function of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to tell that $y^2$ is an even function a priori. Perhaps whoever presented solution confused polynomials in $x$ with even powers with this case and jumped to conclusion that $y^2$ is always even. This is obviously false for a function like $y(x) = x^2 + x$.

A way to solve the first problem that I can see immediately is to use higher derivative test for extrema. We have

$$y' = y^2 - 1 + \cos x \implies y'(0) = y(0)^2-1+\cos 0\stackrel{y(0)=0}{=} 0$$
$$y''= 2yy'-\sin x \implies y''(0) = 2y(0)y'(0)-\sin 0 = 0 $$
$$y''' = 2(y')^2 + 2yy'' - \cos x \implies y'''(0) = 2y'(0)^2+2y(0)y''(0) - \cos 0 = -1$$

We conclude that $y$ has inflection point at the origin, so A and B are false. Furthermore, since $y$ is infinitely times differentiable, in particular $y'''$ is continuous, so there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $y''' < 0$ on $(-\delta,\delta)$. Therefore, $y''$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\delta,\delta)$, so $y'' > 0$ on $(-\delta,0)$ and $y''<0$ on $(0,\delta)$. That means that $y'$ is strictly increasing on $(-\delta,0)$ and strictly decreasing on $(0,\delta)$. Thus, $y' < 0$ on $(-\delta,\delta)\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore, the correct answer is D.

Visualizing this argument:

\begin{array}{c| l c c c r}
 & -\delta && 0 && \delta\\ \hline
y''' && - && -\\ \hline
y'' && \searrow && \searrow \\
    && + && - \\ \hline
y'  && \nearrow && \searrow \\
    && - && - \\ \hline
y   && \searrow && \searrow
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

Consider the symmetric of the solution wrt the origin, i.e. $z(x)=-y(-x)$. You have $z'(x)=y'(-x)$ and the differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}=y'(-x)=y^2(-x)-1+\cos(-x)=z^2(x)-1+\cos(x)$$

Therefore $z$ satisfies the same DE as $y$. The same initial condition $y(0)=z(0)=0$ holds, therefore the solutions are identical, and $y(x)=-y(-x)$, so $y$ is odd.

A maybe more intuitive way to view this: the slope is a function of $y$ and $x$ on a $y$-$x$ plot. And the slope at $(x,y)$ is the same as the slope at $(-x,-y)$ (because $y^2$ is an even function... of $y$). By symmetry of the [slope field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field) wrt the origin, the solution has to be symmetric too, as it passes through the origin.

With the same approach you should be able to solve the other problem.

Comment: +1 for the technique, but we still need to argue uniqueness of the solution in the first problem since it doesn't say so explicitly, no?

Comment: @Ennar You may invoke [Cauchy-Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), but given it's a multiple choice question I wouldn't worry too much about it. It has to be C or D, then your answer allows to find out.